# Can I use Ansible systemd module to halt CoreOS system?

Tags: ansible, systemd, coreos

I just need a simple playbook or ad-hoc syntax to shutdown a group of CoreOS hosts.

Something tells me I may need to use the shell module, which truthfully wouldn't be awful.

The proper way to shutdown a CoreOS host is 'systemctl poweroff'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ansible command module will help you.  I didn't try to use it for halting the servers but have used for different purposes.

**Example**

```
- name: return motd to registered var
  command: cat /etc/motd
  register: mymotd
```